# Can XPath be used to return namespaces on nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

Can XPath (1.0) be used to return the namespace nodes in an XML document?

Note: I am not asking for nodes which have a given namespace, but the namespace nodes themselves. So NOT:

```
//node()[namespace-uri()='http://a.b']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the namespace axis is implemented (Firefox/Mozilla refuses to do that) then `//namespace::node()` gives you all namespace nodes. But note that namespace nodes in the XSLT/XPath data model are different from namespace declaration attributes in the XML document, with the markup

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns">
  <foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

all three elements each have two in scope namespace nodes, the default one declared on the root element and the built-in one for the `xml` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `namespace::` axis in XPath 1.0, so you can. In 2.0 it's deprecated and only works in compatbility mode. You can however query all the namespace bindings/prefixes in scope.

It's usually not a good idea to rely on actual namespace nodes, although sometimes it's unavoidable. Note that the `namespace::` axis contains all the namespace nodes that are in scope for that element. To find the ones that were bound on that specific element, you have to compare your node list to the namespaces in scope for the parent element.

Comment: Do you know why it is deprecated?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust I can only guess but I think it's because it's a very fragile idea. First of all, namespace bindings should really be transparent on XSLT level. Even worse, a single namespace binding is cloned as a new namespace node for each descendant of the element it appears in. That could be quite confusing.

Comment: The namespace axis is deprecated in XPath 2.0 because of the dominant influence of XQuery people who didn't see the need for it. It is NOT deprecated in XSLT 2.0: rather, it is an "optional feature". My definition of an optional feature is a feature that you will find in a good implementation, and won't find in a bad implementation.

Comment: Another comment: the information available via the namespace axis is also available (sometimes less conveniently, but perhaps more efficiently) via the XPath 2.0 functions in-scope-prefixes() and namespace-uri-for-prefix(). I think a major reason that some implementors were keen to deprecate the namespace axis was that they wanted to encourage users to use these functions instead, as they are easier to implement efficiently.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for adding some background info on the history of it. But there's a genuine inconsistency between namespace nodes and all the others, the biggest one being that it doesn't have a one-to-one relationship with what's in the XML file itself.

Comment: Note that the `namespace` axis is clearly marked as deprecated in XPath 2.0. Scroll down from this chapter http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes to the list of axis, the last one is `namespace` and if you read that paragraph is says `The namespace axis is deprecated in XPath 2.0.` and an implementation does not have to implement it even if "backward compatible."