# What is namespace in xpath axes

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking into the XPath Axes and I am able to understand all below axes

'ancestor'
| 'ancestor-or-self'
| 'attribute'
| 'child'
| 'descendant'
| 'descendant-or-self'
| 'following'
| 'following-sibling'
| 'parent'
| 'preceding'
| 'preceding-sibling'
| 'self'

The only axes I am not able to understand is

**| 'namespace'**

Can anyone give me a good example and understanding about what 'namespace' actually do?

Example:-

Open :- https://www.google.co.in/

OR

HTML code

```
<a style="left:-1000em;position:absolute" href="/setprefs?suggon=2&prev=https://www.google.co.in/&sig=0_ujdR1PrGxEbi_EiD6RbIb4VvaXc%3D">Screen-reader users, click here to turn off Google Instant.</a>
```

I am trying the below xpath

```
  //a[@style='left:-1000em;position:absolute']/namespace::*[name()='google']
```

What is wrong I am doing in above namespace?

In addition I also want to know about that what is the use of axes | 'attribute'. where and in which situation it is helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do XML namespaces work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863233/how-do-xml-namespaces-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are XML namespaces for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128389/what-are-xml-namespaces-for)

Comment: Thanks I will look into it

Comment: @Quentin - none of them have any good example.

Comment: Answer updated, it would be great if it somehow helped.

Comment: Also related : [How to retrieve namespaces in XML files using Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122463/how-to-retrieve-namespaces-in-xml-files-using-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the logic, it should select all elements associated with the namespace. However, its behavior is a bit more complicated, hence it is not used often. (It is considered as deprecated in XPath 2.0.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <BASE xmlns:base="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <base:p>XXX</base:p>
        <dc:p>yyy</dc:p>
    </BASE>
    <NEXT xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <p>zzz</p>
    </NEXT>
</ROOT>
```

XPath (2.0):

```
//*[namespace::dc]
```

selects the whole `BASE` element. It is similar to:

```
//*[namespace-uri-for-prefix('dc', .)]
```

which does not work in XPath 1.0.

```
//*[namespace::*='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/']
```

selects both, `BASE` as well as `NEXT` elements. Such a usage is considered a bit strange and it is not recommended.

```
//*[local-name(.) eq 'p' and namespace::*='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/']
```

selects all `p` elements, which means `base:p`, `dc:p`, `p` as well.

```
//*[local-name(.) eq 'p' and namespace::dc]
```

selects `base:p` and `dc:p` of the `BASE` element.

```
//*[local-name(.) eq 'p' and namespace-uri() eq 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/']
```

selects all elements bounded to the URI. It means it is the most accurate option.

Or it is possible to try something like:

```
//*[contains(namespace-uri(), 'purl')]
```

or

```
//self::BASE/*[contains(namespace-uri(), 'purl')]
```

Tested in Oxygen Author 17.1

**UPDATE**

As for your need, it seems you are probably trying to select an element with the string `google` in the `href` attribute, not with a particular namespace. What about `//a[contains(@href, 'google')]`?

**UPDATE II**

As stated in comments, the **UPDATE** was the working solution. However, I think the next information is also useful:

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have added a example in my question .. can you please look into and tell me that what I am doing wrong

Comment: I have posted by issue in question as :- HTML code

<a style="left:-1000em;position:absolute" href="/setprefs?suggon=2&prev=https://www.google.co.in/&sig=0_ujdR1PrGxEbi_EiD6RbIb4VvaXc%3D">Screen-reader users, click here to turn off Google Instant.</a>
I am trying the below xpath

  //a[@style='left:-1000em;position:absolute']/namespace::*[name()='google']
What is wrong I am doing in above namespace?

Comment: please look into it and please let me know what I have done wrong here

Comment: The funny thing is you are probably trying to select an element with the string `google` in the `href` attribute, not with a particular namespace. What about `//a[contains(@href, 'google')]`?

Comment: :D ....  ya that above xpath will work .. actually I am new for axes and only namespace was not working for me.. I got an idea .. moreover , may be it is deprecated so it is not working in my firepath .. thanks a alot .. :D

Answer (score 4):

`namespace::` axis selects **[*namespace nodes*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#namespace-nodes)**. Nothing fancy.

And ***namespace nodes***, according to the linked specs includes :

- every attribute on the element whose name starts with `xmlns:`
- every attribute on an ancestor element whose name starts `xmlns:` unless the element itself or a nearer ancestor redeclares the prefix
- an `xmlns` attribute, if the element or some ancestor has an `xmlns` attribute, and the value of the `xmlns` attribute for the nearest such element is non-empty

For example, given the following XML element :

```
<a xmlns:google="some namespace uri here"/>
```

XPath expression below will return the `xmlns:google` attribute <sup>[[demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/45582cc8007bbcf8e327e454cc647360)]</sup>. :

```
//a/namespace::*[name()='google']
```

This example corresponds to the first bullet point mentioned above, since `xmlns:google` is *attribute, on the context element `<a>`, whose name starts with `xmlns:`*.

---

Similar explanation goes for `attribute` axis; it simply selects XML attributes.

You can consider `attribute` axis as a longer version of `@` which you've already been using. For example, the two expressions below mean the same :

```
//a[attribute::style='left:-1000em;position:absolute']
//a[@style='left:-1000em;position:absolute']
```

Comment: Could you provide similar example with `namespace::`? When compared to attributes, there is a problem because it is possible to declare namespace in two basic ways (in a parent element, as an attribute of the current element). People often think it is usable for selecting of particular elements **in** a particular namespace. It could be convenient but I think there is no way how to do that.

Comment: *"Could you provide similar example with namespace::?"*. Do you mean example that filter element by namespace value/URI, like this : `//a[namespace::*='some namespace uri here']` ?

Comment: I have tried the same in my local but it is not working .. I have added 
<a foo="bar" xmlns:google="some namespace uri here"/> in my HTML and try to search it by //a/namespace::*[name()='google'] .. the result is empty

Comment: @ShubhamJain Maybe the XPath processor you used doesn't implement `namespace` axis? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11189061/2998271

Comment: ya may be .. because I am trying many different combination with namespace and it is not working for me.. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, I mean using the `namespace::` axis in an element’s predicate. For me it does not work either. I am testing in Oxygen Author 17.1, XPath 1.0, XPath 2.0. @har07, could you describe your technical scenario, please?

Comment: @HonzaHejzl I tested in xpathtester.com : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ae2d285ae84b292608620462db71b7a1 . I *guess*, the site is using Java XPath engine, maybe Saxon

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm it works. However, it works **only** if the namespace is declared directly for the element, as an attribute. If it is declared in the root element as a default namespace or if it is declared in the root and used as a prefix, it does not work. I think there is no clean solution. The funny thing is the initial question is a typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), we are trying to answer to Y but X was needed. In spite of this, useful question.

Comment: Still worked when the namespace declared at the root element : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ed8fb2ec5c3c0478d9250005f3c412ca . Maybe I misunderstand the scenario which didn't work as per your comment

Comment: What about [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/04a6547e2cf824e411d3ae7780a90fa3)? Please do not consider this as a game, I only want to shape the answer as properly as possible.

Comment: @HonzaHejzl The reason why the XPath you linked to yielded no result has nothing to do with the `namespace` in predicate. It is because `<a>` inherits default namespace now, so even just `//a` would have returned no result. Compare your XPath with this one : `//*[local-name()='a' and namespace::*='some namespace uri here']`

Comment: Could I use that in the answer? Just for the sake of completeness? You are right, thanks, nice lesson!

Comment: No problem, feel free to include that in your answer