# What will Xpath return in PHP for XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

There is a code that is applied to XML

```
$Xlist = $xpath->query('./namespace::*', $node)
```

What is supposed to be returned as a result of execution?

Comment: I don't fully understand this: './namespace::*'

Comment: Looks like an error to me. `list` is a reserved keyword in PHP. Also I don't see a `$` in front of the variable.

Comment: This might help you understand the namespace axis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031991/what-is-namespace-in-xpath-axes

Comment: @KevinY Yes, I cut beginning. Sorry, it's my error.